# Representing all pairs shortest path in a graph with a matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Given a graph $G(n,E)$ where $n$ is the number of nodes and $E$ represents the edges.

Is there a way to represent or transform this into a matrix containing all the shortest paths between two pairs of nodes $i$ and $j$?

Comment: There may be expotentially many such paths, so your only option is some compact representation. Perhaps the length of the shortest path between any pair of vertices will be enought for you?

Comment: You will, at the very least, need to add an assumption that there are no negative-weight cycles, since otherwise the shortest paths are not well defined.

Comment: i am actually looking for the length of the shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the min-plus matrix (see [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-plus_matrix_multiplication)) that (iterated) will give you the length of the shortest path.